# Memory effects in open quantum systems: Markovian approximation question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, open-quantum-systems

**Setting:** Quantum system $S$ composed of a subsystem of interest $A$ and a subsystem acting as the environment $B$ such that $S=A\cup B$. System $S$ is described by density matrix $\rho$ whereas subsystem $A$ is described by $\rho_A = \text{Tr}_B \rho$, as usual.

**Question:** Given a *dynamical map* $V(t)$ that time evolves $\rho_A$, i.e. $V(t):\rho_A(0) \mapsto \rho_A(t)$, why if memory effects are small/negligible (i.e. Markovian approx.) then
$$
V(t_1)V(t_2)=V(t_1+t_2) \quad t_1,t_2>0 \quad ?
$$
Or conversely, why if $V(t_1)V(t_2)\neq V(t_1+t_2)$ then memory effects are not negligible?

**My troubles:** I cant even think of a system, for artificial it may be, where $V(t_1)V(t_2)\neq V(t_1+t_2)$, $V$ knows of the entire system. Would memory effects be included, shouldn’t they be already described by the Hamiltonian of the system and executed by the time evolution operator with the semi-group property?

Comment: Just consider a system where the evolution exchanges A and B in every step.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I don’t see why that wouldn’t satisfy $V(t_1)V(t_2)=V(t_1+t_2)$. I was thinking that for a simple 2 fermion system $\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ with initial state $|0_A\rangle \otimes |1_B\rangle$ your evolution operator could be something like $f_A^{\dagger}\otimes f_B$ for even steps and c.c. for odd steps. The Markovian condition simply reads: $(f_A\otimes f_B^{\dagger})(f_A^{\dagger}\otimes f_B)|0_A\rangle \otimes |1_B\rangle \equiv (1_A\otimes 1_B) |0_A\rangle \otimes |1_B\rangle$ which is of the form $V(t_1)V(t_2)=V(t_1+t_2)$ no?

Comment: Now that I think about it, should one impose $t_1>t_2$ so that tricks like $V(t_1)V(t_2)=V(t_1+t_2)=V(t_2+t_1)=V(t_2)V(t_1) \implies [V(t_1),V(t_2)]=0$ are forbidden?

Comment: What *is* V in that setting in your opinion?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch in my humble understanding $V_t : \rho(0) \mapsto \rho(t)$, so basically $V(t)$ grabs $\rho(0)$ and times evolve it: it's the time evolution operator for the reduced density matrix. It must be similar in many regards to the unitary time evolution operator of standard QM but with the crucial difference that it "knows of" the rest of the system. Therefore $V$ must in general be non unitary to incorporate the subsystem-bath interactions. Mathematically, with the semi-group property, $V$ can be casted in the familiar form $V(t)=\exp (Lt)$ with $L$ the generator, yet to be found.

Comment: That's to me the idea behind $V$ and its semi-group condition, but I yet don't see why this condition implies Markovian dynamics, i.e. getting rid of memory effects.